How to avoid async function retaining self
I have example code below, the problem is that self is retained for the duration of fetchMovies function, is there any way to avoid that without explicitly holding task and cancelling it?
If I move the contents of fetch movies call inside Task directly then self is not retained, my real code is more complex and I don't want to keep everything in one function.
I could probably make fetchMovies static and pass optional self as parameter but I feel like I am missing something very obvious here.
class TestViewModel {
    init() {
        print("Init")
        Task { [weak self] in
            await self?.fetchMovies()
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("Deinit")
    }
    
    func fetchMovies() async {
        try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 3 * 1_000_000_000)
    }
}

I tried moving it in external class but that is not what I want.

In short, no, once fetchMovies starts, it will retain self until it finishes (whether in the course of its normal process, or until canceled). A SwiftUI .task view modifier will cancel it for you, but in UIKit, you have to manually cancel the task (say, in viewDidDisappear).

@Rob Thank you for answering. I did read the duplicate question and your answer, I just don't think that it explicitly answers my question, especially about function2() in that question where it seems to me that it is assumed that [weak self] will resolve the problem but it won't.

Agreed. I tried to clarify point 3 (which previously focused simply on properties of self) to also touch upon the scenario where you are calling a method of self. Regardless, I hope your question is answered sufficiently. The long-and-short of it is that [weak self] capture lists are not generally the right solution within Swift concurrency: We really want to adopt cancelation patterns. (FWIW, the same was actually true for GCD, too, but was frequently ignored given how tricky proper cancelation could be in GCD.
